# Create OHLC plotly charts with less than four values

Tags: r, plotly

I was wondeing if it is somehow possible to create an OHLC chart in plotly with R with less than the default four values `open,close,high,low`. Of course I have tried with 2 or 3 but without result. But what if I have only the `open` and `close` values or only `high` and low `values`?

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL",src='yahoo')

df <- data.frame(Date=index(AAPL),coredata(AAPL))
df <- tail(df, 30)

p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="ohlc",
          open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
          high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic OHLC Chart")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot provide less than all 4, but they don't all have to be different, so you can set `high` to the max of `open` and `close` and `low` to the min, or something like this, if you like.

Comment: the issue is that inside the hover box I have 4 values instead of 2 which would seem more meaningful. Could I set the hoverbox info?

Comment: Unfortunately not.